# How does importing module in JavaScript works?

Tags: javascript, typescript, module, requirejs, system.js

I want to know the difference between :

> import 'any module which is in node_module';
>
> import 'any module which is in vendor folder';
>
> require('any module in node_module');
>
> require('module in vendor folder');

I know that **require** function needs require.js. But sometimes, in projects,
there is no require.js. But there is system.js.

Then what is the difference between require.js and system.js ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Both are module loaders . They will load javascript modules in a lazy load manner.